# İ have problem about VS code Select yo Kernel problem

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can fix it? When i click Select a Kernel button i have to Select Python environments and other button Install Python when i click that i saw like this thing "installing Python extension and locating kernels" later gave to me a error  just fail.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUKqf.jpg)

How can fix it? When i click Select a Kernel button i have to Select Python environments and other button Install Python when i click that i saw like this thing "installing Python extension and locating kernels" later gave to me a error  just fail.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a python environment on your machine, vscode to install **[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)** extensions. The first time you open an interactive window you will be asked to install `ipykernel`.

*[Details are in the start documentation.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)*

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py*

[image]